# In Quantum cosmology, is the evolution operator idempotent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology

In normal quantum field theory there is a time evolution operator $U(t)$. Written as a matrix $U(t)^{AB}$ it takes a state $A$ of the Universe to a state $B$ of the Universe after time t. We have

$$U(t_1+t_2)^{AC} = \sum_B U^{AB}(t_1)U^{BC}(t_2)$$

Summing over all intermediate states.

But in quantum cosmology, there is no time, since time is a property of the 3-dimensional space. i.e. you determine cosmological time somehow from how big and complex the Universe is.

This suggests that the evolution operator does not depend on time. The states $A$ and $B$ are the 3-dimensional metrics of particular slices of space-time. It suggests an evolution operator not dependent on t. If we assume the same rule:

$$U^{AC} = \sum_B U^{AB}U^{BC}$$

In other words $U^2=U$ in quantum cosmology. This sort of suggests that $U=1$ and that amplitude to get from any state of the Universe to any other is 1. This doesn't make sense to me. What is the error in the reasoning above?

Comment: I have little understanding of quantum cosmology, but from the point of view of formulae: $U^{AA} = \sum_{B} U^{AB} U^{BA}$. Sounds like unitarity condition?

Comment: 1. $U^2 = U$ does not imply $U=1$ in any way - there are many *idempotent* (*nilpotent* as in your title would mean $U^2 = 0$) operators that are not the identity. 2. If there really is no time in quantum cosmology, what is the "evolution operator" supposed to do in the first place? What reference for quantum cosmology did you look at before asking this question?

Comment: "evolution operator" in this case is the amplitude to get from state A to state B as opposed to state C for example. Exactly, what does it do? Maybe nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no time in quantum cosmology, and thus no evolution operator.

An operator *analogous* to $U$ is the projection operator $\mathcal{P}$ associated with the Hamiltonian constraint. It determines the physical inner product between kinematical states:

$$ \left< \Phi | \Psi \right>_{\text{physical}} = \left< \Phi | \mathcal{P} | \Psi \right>. $$

This is indeed required to satisfy
$$ \mathcal{P}^2 = \mathcal{P}. $$

Note that this relation is satisfied by any projection operator, and absolutely does not mean that $\mathcal{P} = 1$.

Comment: What meaning does the physical inner product have? Is there a simple way to understand it? (I know nothing is simple about quantum cosmology!) My guess is that it means you can smoothly get from one state to the other.

Comment: @zooby the physical meaning of the physical inner product is: $\left| \left<\Phi | \Psi \right> _{\text{physical}} \right|^2$ can be interpreted as a probability of observing state $\Phi$ when the system is in state $\Psi$. This is the usual Born rule. The only difference is that it involves the *physical* inner product.